# Internal Passive With Characteristic "u" Vowel

Tags: grammar-dikduk

In Biblical Hebrew, what is the "internal passive with characteristic *u* vowel"?

Comment: Welcome to judaism.SE! Where did this quoted phrase come from?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Biblical-Hebrew-Phonology-Morphology-Introduction/dp/1575061295

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are referring to the adjectival form "*qatul*", in which the *u* vowel is inserted between the second and third letters of the root. It denotes the passive of a *pa'al* verb, usually functioning to modify a noun. For example, *etz shatul* (Psalms 1).

Comment: Meaning "a tree *planted*"

Comment: Another good one is Genesis 30:33, *ganuv* (from the root *gnb*), "any such sheep are *stolen*"

Comment: Where *gnb* is the root for "steal"

Comment: Isn't that a passive participle rather than an adjective?

Comment: @Andrew J. Brehm - Yes, it is the passive participle. Biblical Hebrew didn't have much in the way of actual adjectives. However, it functionally serves what English speakers would consider an adjectival role and in later Hebrews came to be used as such.

Comment: One of the remnants of the long-lost pa3al passive conjugation, I assume.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to forms like

- huf'al, passive of hif'il: hukhtav הוכתב
- pu'al, passive of pi'el: dubar דובר

And also to the extinct  qal internal passive, found only rarely and in altered form in Hebrew, e.g. yullad ילד ) יולד), Ruth 4:17.

Comment: Welcome to judaism.SE and thanks very much for contributing your grammatical expertise!